# Problems when calling a public sub

Tags: vb.net

I'm facing a deadend When trying to call this sub :

```
   Public Sub backblue(ByVal frm As Form, ByVal boxname As String)
      For i = 1 To 3
          CType(frm.Controls(boxname & i.ToString()), TextBox).BackColor = Color.LightBlue
      Next
   End Sub
```

with button click event :

```
      Private Sub Button1_click and bla bla....
         backblue(Me, "txb1_")
      End Sub
```

Can anybody show me a suggestion to fix the code.

It throws "Object Referrence not set to an instance bla bla" error

For information the textbox names are :
txb1_1 , txb1_2 , txb1_3 
(these are some of the many textboxes in the form that i want its bakcolor changed)

and these three textboxes are already created through designer, not from execution.

i did check the textboxes names and there's nothing wrong.

the form class is also public.

Comment: You are likely getting the name of the textboxes wrong.

Comment: What are the names of the textboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

```
Public Sub backblue(ByVal frm As Form, ByVal prefix As String)
   For i = 1 To 3
        Dim bxName as String = prefix & i.ToString()
        Dim bx as TextBox = CType(frm.Controls(bxName), TextBox)
       If bx Is Nothing Then
          MsgBox("Unable to find text box " +bxName)
          Dim mtch() As Control = frm.Controls.Find(bxName, true)
          If mtch.Length> 0 then
              bx = mtch(0)
          Else
              Continue For
          End if
        End If
       Bx.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
   Next
End Sub
```

Although, a better solution would be to either create the textboxes inside a control and pass that control to BackBlue or to create an collection that has the controls and pass that in.  Which brings up what is most likely yor problem **your control is contained in a sub component and thus is not in the main form control collection**

Alternative, you could use either the tag of the control or create a component control that implements IExtenderProvider and add it to the form --all of the above would effectively allow you to define the controls and/how they should be handled at designtime.

Answer (score 2):

if they are the only textboxs on said form you can just loop through

```
For Each box as Textbox In frm.Controls
box.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
Next
```

Comment: this for each loop would only work if and only if the whole form contained Textboxes...nothing but textboxes so maybe code would be put in the form's Load method

Comment: Yes as the OP's code is only after textbox's, can be changed for any control or all. just depends on OP's need :)

Answer (score 2):

1. This error will occur if you do not declare the Form class to be public.
2. Also, make sure the textbox names are really correct, although this will probably cause a different error.
3. If you create the textboxes during execution, make sure they are initialized with New and added to the form's Controls collection.

Answer (score 1):

It may really seem that the names generated by this loop may not be the names of the original textboxes. My suggestion is before setting this Color property verify that the names generated by this loop are indeed the actual names. Maybe output this in a messagebox:
`MessageBox.Show(boxname & i.ToString())` for each loop before you set the property